# Changing a TF Dataset from classified to numeric/regression data

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

This is my first attempt at branching out from ready-made datasets and models to something pieced together on my own.  Using tensorflow, I'm trying to load a dataset of images where each image is assigned a normalized, numeric value so that I can try to build a regression CNN over it.
Unfortunately for me, `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` expects the dataset to be discretely classified.
Is there a straightforward way to *convert* the BatchDataset object to a numeric labeling?

For further clarification, if I were to do a `dir(my_dataset)` or `my_dataset.__dict__`, I would like to know where the labels are.

Comment: if you get error then show it in question. always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: i don't understand what is the problem. Load it, preprocess it and later convert labels to numbers (`LabelEncoding`) and you can use it with regression.

Comment: I apologize if my question sounded like a complaint.  I am not debugging an error, I'm asking for more information about the DataSet datastructure.  I will read more about `LabelEncoder`  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this after poking around a little more at the `BatchDataSet` object returned from `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`

Because these objects are very specialized iterators, it's not straightforward to access a single "row."
The following is how I got direct access to where this information is located from a BatchDataSet.

```
training_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "assets/",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    color_mode="rgb",
    image_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size=32)
# pull one batch from the BatchDataSet
one_batch = training_ds.take(1)
# transform the TakeDataset into a python iterator and then pull one batch using next()
training_data, labels = next(iter(batch))
# labels is a numpy array of int32 where each integer is the index of the class inside training_ds.class_names
```